# Replace repetitions of specific text with perl script

Tags: regex, perl, text, replace

I have a simple perl script that does a number of text replacements along the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
{
open(my $in, "<", "Texts.txt") or die "No input: $!";
open(my $out, ">",  "TeXed/Texts.tex") or die "No output directory: $!";
LINE: while (<$in>) {
    s/(txt@)(.*)(?<!\t|\[)\[(.*)/\1\2\\ovl{}\3/g;# 
    # there are a bunch of other replacements like the above
    print $out $_ ; 
    }
}
```

So far so good. The text I am running this script on is organized into blocks (not always of the same length). Each block starts with the same identifier (txt@) and then a unique label. Every label starts with a #.
What I would like to achieve is to delete all repeated labels – essentially I only want to keep every first instance of a label and replace/delete all subsequent ones until the label changes. In the below example the ones to be replaced/deleted are in **bold**.

txt@#Label1 some text
some more text
some more text

txt@#**Label1** some other text
some more text
some more text
some more text

txt@#**Label1** some random text
some more text
some more text

txt@#Label2 some text
some more text
some more text
some more text

txt@#Label1 some text
some more text
some more text

txt@#Label3 some text
some more text
some more text

txt@#**Label3** some text
some more text
some more text

txt@#Label1 some text
some more text
some more text

etc.

Sorry for the long example – I couldn't come up with a better way of explaining this.

So I want to delete all repeated Label1, Label2, etc., but without modifying the rest of the text (some text, some more text) both on the same line but also on subsequent lines. The number of subsequent lines is not always the same (so it's not every n-th line that has to be replaced).

Is that possible with perl?  Or any other way?  (I'm not married to perl, if it is easier with another language I'd be happy to try that – I'm not a programmer though so detailed instructions would be highly appreciated).

Comment: Do you want to keep the text as well?  How do you want to ogranize output?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the text has to be kept (I just edited the post to make it clearer).  The output should be kept the way it is organized, there are a number of other replacement operations that I run on the text, but no lines are deleted.

Comment: OK. So the lines with duplicate labels just literally lose the label and everything else stays the same?

Comment: It does work!!! Great, thanks so much for the prompt solution!  -- Just one more thing:  I'd like to get rid of the hashtag too (which is part of the label).

Comment: Fixed. Since nothing depended on that regex (other than deletion) it was as simple as moving the `#` into the non-capturing group.  Then the replacement doesn't put it back.  Let me know if more comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce the 'current label' -- the latest one picked up -- and keep track of it. Once a line with a label comes up compare: if it is the same it repeats so delete it, otherwise replace it and we have the new 'current' one.

The processing goes line-by-line. Alternatively, one can read a whole block at a time to enable per-block processing, which may be more convenient. Code for this is shown at the end.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh_out, '>', 'new_text_label.txt';
open my $fh_in, '<', 'text_label.txt';

# Our current (running) label
my $curr_label = '';

while (<$fh_in>)  
{
    # If line with label fetch it otherwise (print and) skip
    my ($label) = $_ =~ m/txt@#(\w+)/;
    if (not $label) {
        # ... process non-label line as needed ...
        print $fh_out $_;
        next;
    }       
    # Delete if repeated (matching the current), reset if new
    if ($curr_label eq $label) {
        s/(txt@)(?:#\w+)(.*)/$1$2/;
    }   
    else {
        $curr_label = $label;
    }   
    # ... process label-line as needed ...
    print $fh_out $_;
}
```

This yields the required file.  Processing of lines with or without a label is separate, which may be good if further processing differs for them.  Or, the pre-processing of the label-line can be all done in one place, which is better if further processing does not distinguish between lines with or without a label.

```
while (<$fh_in>) 
{
     # If this is the label line, process it: delete or replace the label
     if (my ($label) = $_ =~ m/txt@#(\w+)/) {
        # Delete if repeated (matching the current), reset if new
        if ($curr_label eq $label) {
            s/(txt@)(?:#\w+)(.*)/$1$2/;
        }   
        else {
            $curr_label = $label;
        }
     }
     # The label is now fixed as needed. Process lines normally ...
     print $fh_out $_;
}
```

This replaces the `while` loop above, the rest of the code is the same.

---

*Derived from what was originally posted, commented*

Here are changes in the code so that it reads the whole block at a time, which is good for processing that can make use of having the whole block of text in the variable. Note that a block contains new lines (so regexes may need `/s` etc). To enable possible bulk processing all blocks are first read into an array as well.

```
my @blocks = do { 
    # Set record separator to empty line to read blocks
    local $/ = "\n\n";
    open my $fh_in, '<', 'text_label.txt';
    <$fh_in>;    
};

# Our current (running) label
my $curr_label = '';

foreach my $bl (@blocks) 
{
     # The label pre-processing is exactly the same as above
     # Other processing can now utilize having the whole block in $bl
}
```

Comment: Yes it works now (I might have copied something wrong).  One more question: Where should I put the rest of my regexes (to be processed after the label replacement)?  I tried to put the `LINE: while ...` sequence before the `print` command but it gives me an error.

Comment: OK, no worries, I'll play around with it.  It's not urgent.  I've now put the `s/` patterns in the loop (before the print) but get a `Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///)` error?

Comment: @jan  Changed and rearranged the code.  Now it starts with a version that processes line-by-line.  You should be able to literally copy your regexes (and whatever other processing you have), to where it says "process ...". It still gives you two options: where label and non-label lines are distinguished, or not. Then it shows what change in code to make if you wish to do per-block processing (that was the original post).  It's all been tested.  Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: @jan  The error you were getting was because your regex uses the default `$_` while I had had a named variable `$bl`.  I changed that around as well so that you can simply copy your code.  In principle I do recommend using properly named variables, specially in complex processing that calls `$_` often.  The code's often just clearer that way.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much!   First and second versions work fine.  I'm using the second solution since other replacements search both, label and no-label lines.  In the first version I tested putting these other replacements at the beginning, before the block with labels starts, and it worked as well.  When would one be preferred over the other?   (I didn't get the processing in blocks to work, despite changing $_ to $bl but I'm happy with what I've got!)

Comment: May I ask you two more questions?  I'm trying to print a string at the beginning and at the end of the file.  Doing `s/^^/mystring/;` prints it at each line.  Where do I put it?   –  And: how would I pass a currently selected file as variable to the perl script?  (or would that merit a separate question?)

Comment: @jan (1) That regex is a substition at the beginning of a line, that works on the default parameter `$_`.  So it will do it at the beginning of each line as `$_` is set to a new line.  (I don't know what the double `^^` does exactly, if anything.)  If the string has nothing to do with the file contents, just print it before `while` -- before you start iterating over lines.  Do `print $out "string\n";`. Then do the same after the `while` finishes.  Your lines are processed inside `while`, but the `$out` refers to the file everywhere. (2) What do you mean by "currently selected" file?

Comment: @jan My comment above is about _adding_ a string to the top of the file.  If the string is to be at the beginning of the existing first line of the file let me know.

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted! Thank you.  – By "selected file" I was referring to a file in the Finder, in order to be able to call this script from the GUI by embedding it in an AppleScript for example, via a `do shell script "./myscript.pl -i inputFile -o outputFile` where input and output Files are variables that I get from the AppleScript.  How do I make sure that the perl scrips understands these variables?

Comment: @jan  OK, I dont' know anything about the particular AppleScript integration.  However, if you do have the variable to pass to your script like `myscript.pl -i inputFile`, then you want to look at the excellent module [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html), which provides great interface for handling _command line options_.  There are posts around here about how to use it. I'll look for some and send links.

Comment: @jan  I see your comment about versions only now.  I'd say: if all lines are processed the same way, better pre-process the label at one place and then you have a clean slate.  If the processing of lines differs, then it may make sense to use the version that already splits those cases.  As for blocks ... imagine you have a pattern/sentence/etc that spreads over the block.  Or, some other target where you need to look at the whole block.  That's when it is nice to have the block in a variable. (Keep in mind that there are newlines in the block as well.)  Otherwise, go line-by-line.

Comment: @jan I started with block because at first I thought that it would be a good way to do what you need. Then it turned out unnecessary.  I kept it in the end just so, since it may be good to know about that possibility.

Comment: @jan  Glad to hear that. As for Getopt, all I can readily find here is my own [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661880/read-optional-command-line-arguments-in-perl/35661939#35661939), which summarizes common usage.  Here is also a [hands-on post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=455158) on perlmonks, where the first and specially second answer seem to be helpful.  Finally, I'd suggest that we tidy up this thread, remove your comments that you don't need here and then I'll do the same.

Comment: @jan That's fine. These threads do get cleaned up occasionally if needed.  If anything else pops up please let me know. Thank you for nice interaction.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help!